# Error while compling my app in Flutter in VScode and android studio

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main () {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Text('Hello!'),);
  }
}
```

This is my app on Flutter when I run main.dart, the following error shows up. I have installed Android Studio correctly with an emulator working. I use VS Code to edit. I run git bash as terminal. Flutter doctor states everything is working perfectly fine.

How can I fix my issue?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\myCode\myApp\my_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\myCode\myApp\my_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Access is denied)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: `Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network` is mostly related to an unstable internet connection. Can you delete the Gradle and install it again?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved

find the file "signing-config.json" and change the permissions to full control
C:\Users\shubh\OneDrive\Desktop\myCode\myApp\my_app\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json